# malloc() for array of structure objects

Tags: c++, malloc

Trying to understand how to manage memory in C++ using C style:

```
struct aaa{
public:
    int a ;
    int b ;
    std::string c ;
};

int asize =5;

int main() 
{
    aaa * a;
    a = static_cast<aaa *>(malloc(sizeof(aaa) * asize));
    for (int i;i<asize;i++)
    {
        a[i] =  aaa(); //crash
    }
    a[0].c = "ddd";
    a[1].c = "ccc";
    a[2].c = "eee";
}
```

Programm crash while creating structure object in first memory segment. What I do wrong (except doing C in C++) ?

Comment: The problem is that you're using `malloc`. Don't use `malloc`, use `new`.

Comment: `std::malloc` doesn't call the constructor of a type. It is legal if the constructor of the type you want to construct is trivial, but yours isn't, because of `c`.

Comment: but I call constructor manually in `for(...)`

Comment: @vico You construct an `aaa()` then **move-assign**  it to `a[i]`. The correct way to call the constructor on the storage for `a[i]` would be to use `new (&a[i]) aaa()` or `new (a + i) aaa()`.

Comment: Use std::vector.

Comment: why did you call malloc? All the explanations of how to use malloc and make the constructors work are irrelevant if you dont have a good (rare) reason for using malloc.

Comment: BTW you use `new[]` to allocate an array

Comment: @jotik `But a[i] =  new (a + i) aaa()` gives error `error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘aaa’ and ‘aaa*’)`

Comment: @vico Don't do the assignment, only do the the placement new. The whole statement should be `new (a + i) aaa();`. No assignment needed. It just constructs an `aaa` object at address `a + i`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't copy into object for which you didn't call constructor:

```
a[i] =  aaa(); //crash
```

You can do like that:

```
new (a + i) aaa();
a[i] =  aaa(); //no crash
```

Class has non-trivial default constructor if at least of its non-static members has not trivial default constuctor. In your case `std::string c` doesn't have trivial default constructor, so malloc in this case is not enough.